# Как отфильтровать массив объектов?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<ui_graph_search :values="getStatus" @select="changeArray('status_id', 'where', $event)" :multiple="true">Статус</ui_graph_search>
<ui_chip removeByCallback v-for="selected in filterArray.status_id" @delete="removeFromWhereIn('status_id', 'where', $event)" :item="selected">{{ selected.name }}</ui_chip>



changeArray(name, subname, value) {
    if (this.filterArray[name].length < 2) {
        this.filterArray[name].push(value)
        var filterId = this.filterArray[name].map((item)=>{
            return item.id
        })

        var i = filterId.length,
            result = [];
        while(i--) {
            if (result.join('').search(filterId[i]) == '-1') {
                result.push(filterId[i])
            }
        }
        this.$store.dispatch('table/updateFilter', { name: name, subname: subname, value: result});
    }
},
```

В `filterArray.status_id` при выборе двух одинаковых статусов падают одинаковые объекты.

Подскажите, как отфильтровать массив объектов так, чтобы, если вдруг у объекта совпадает `id`, он не добавлялся.

Не понимаю в какой момент времени все это происходит.

UPDATE:
на выходе например получается вот такая конструкция

```
[obj, obj1, obj2]

obj = {
    id: 222
},
obj1 = {
    id: 333
},
obj2 = {
    id: 222
}
```

А нужно отфильтровать массив, чтобы на выходе было `[obj, obj1]`

Comment: Ваш вопрос настолько непонятен, что сперва даже непонятно, что он непонятен. Попробуйте привести пример данных, которые прилетают на входе, и пример того, что вы хотите видеть на выходе.

Comment: @Darth Обновил вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Если после `map(item => item.id)` выходит такое `[{id:222},{id:333}, ...]`, то значит
`filterArray[name]` у вас такой конструкции -

```
[
  {id: {id: 444}},  
  {id: {id: 333}},  
  {id: {id: 222}}
]
```

А `result.join('')` дает такую строку - `"[object Object][object Object][object Object]"` и неудивительно, что ничего не фильтруется.

```js
console.log([{id:222},{id:333},{id:444}].join(''))
```

Чтобы найти дубли, я заменил вашу конструкцию -

`result.join('').search(filterId[i]) == '-1'`

на

`!result.find(el => el.id ==filterId[i].id)`

```js
const filterArray = [[ { id: {id: 222}}]];

function changeArray(name, subname, value) {
    if (filterArray[name].length < 2) {
        filterArray[name].push(...value);
        var filterId = filterArray[name].map(item => item.id);
        
        var i = filterId.length,
            result = [];
        while(i--)
            if (!result.find(el => el.id ==filterId[i].id))
                result.push(filterId[i]);
        
        console.log({name, subname, value: result});
        // this.$store.dispatch('table/updateFilter', { name: name, subname: subname, value: result});
   }
}

changeArray(0 ,2, [{id:{id:444}},  { id: {id: 333}},  { id: {id: 222}}]);
```

Comment: я возможно не правильно объяснил. После выполнения map(item => item.id) на выходе получаю только число. Точнее номер ID как раз.

Comment: попробуйте сделать [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) бага

Comment: Может так попробую объяснить: когда вызываю `console.log(this.filterArray[name])` , то получаю как писал ранее массив объектов. Когда вызываю `console.log(item.id)` получаю только число (значение выбранного id)

Comment: Примерно вот так получается https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgaNoe @Darth

Comment: @АлександрКотов Однако, если добавить остальной ваш код, то фильтр работает - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WOYwLv?editors=0011.

Comment: в этом и вся проблема... Этот код отрабатывает после того как в `filterArray.status_id` попадают объекты - `this.filterArray[name].push(value)` и мне надо придумать какое условие для фильтрации написать @Darth